# Configuring Logback to retrieve variables from JBoss

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly, logback

I have several .war files deployed within a Wildfly JBoss container.
I would like these to use a property from an external properties file within the Wildfly Configuration.

I can get this working for beans within beans / spring.xml via:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myProperties" jndi-name="java:jboss/properties/myproperties" />
    <bean id="exampleBean" class="com.package.beanclass">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${logfile.location}"/>
    </bean>
```

But I am trying to reference the ${logfile.location} variable from this external properties file via the logback.xml file.

I have tried:

```
    <configuration>
      <property file="java:jboss/properties/myproperties"/>
      <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>{logfile.location}/logFile.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
          <!-- daily rollover -->
          <fileNamePattern>{logfile.location}/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    
          <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    
        <encoder>
          <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
      </appender> 
    
      <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
      </root>
    </configuration>
```

and I have tried swapping 'file' to 'resource'.

But I'm always getting:

```
File property is set to [log.location_IS_UNDEFINED ..
```

What do I need to do to read from this external properties file so I can read values from logback.xml ?

Comment: Where do you define the `logfile.location` system property?

Comment: Hi James, sorry there was a typo in there when posting a cutdown which I corrected. I've managed to resolve this using <insertFromJNDI>, though it seemed to retrieve the whole file contents as a single string rather than a single property. I just had to do some string manipulation to get the properties I was after.